# Cause of Render Problem In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

Hello guys i would like to ask some problem that i have met in `Android studio` when I'm designing the application, when I'm designing layout the view in the xml I change the from design to text, then go to design tab, after I got error render problem, my zoom or minus button in design page cannot be pressed anymore and stuck at how many percent that I have zoom before. The problem it's not fix even after I deleted the problem in the code which I put wrong

I have tried to make a new one xml, it's not a problem but after i tried to copy and paste the problematic xml to the new one, the new one get the same problem too.

But if I put the fix one into the new one, the problem will not occurred but if make error in text then switch tab to design got problem in render the zoom button stuck again, is this the problem of android studio or is it my problem of my `android studio`? In my previous experience I had never encountered something like this. Currently I'm using the `AS 3.2.1`.

**Edited:**
this is my current xml which have been corrected,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:frisson="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:id="@+id/activity_main"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#fff"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ec018b00"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <include layout="@layout/contact_toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <com.intrusoft.library.FrissonView
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:id="@+id/wave_head"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                frisson:tideCount="3"
                frisson:tideHeight="40dp"
                frisson:gradientType="linear"
                frisson:alphaValue="100"
                frisson:tintColor="@color/green_700"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                frisson:cardCornerRadius="60dp">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/sample_ic_happy"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

but when I put some error in the ImageView for example:

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_ic_happy2"/>
```

**Note:** *@drawable/sample_ic_happy2* there is no resources in the drawable and this make render problem which got stuck in the design tab as you can see in my uploaded picture below:
[image: Zoom Button stuck at the percent and can't be click]

Then I fix the **drawable src** to the correct one which *@drawable/sample_ic_happy*, which means the problems have been solved right? but the problem is my zomm button still stuck because of the render error before and cannot be clicked, why?

Comment: it's possible from all sides. can you post your xml?

Comment: Please show your xml where you are facing problem

Answer (score 0):

It's an eternity problem. I've got the same one periodically.

First of all try to rebuild project - in most cases it helps.
If not - see advises from this page: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-rendering-problem-in-Android-Studio-See-error-screenshot

I mean the first one (to lower API level) and the second one (about custom view).

Hope, it'll help you.

Comment: you mean to lower the API in the gradle or the API in the design preview one? I have tried to lower the design preview one but there is no respond it's still got me the error

Comment: A design preview API. You can try to clean up the project and rebuild it. Sometimes it helps.

Comment: yap sometimes i try rebuild it + clean project + restart cache, it's true the problem is fix, but sometimes after you working  it's comeback again that's why i confuse is there any solution for this? It's rather annoying when you typing all in text tab then go to the design got render problem error needed to restart again for using it.